# Enviar id em um campo hidden ao clicar em um item do autocomplete.js

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, autocompletar

Preciso que seja enviado o id do cliente para um campo hidden ao clicar no nome dele que é trazido pelo autocomplete do jquery.
O autocomplete já esta funcionando ok.. o que eu preciso mesmo é que ao clicar seja enviado o ID para o campo hidden.

> html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="cadastroAdm.php" method="post" name="clientForm">

          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label for="clienteNome" class="control-label">Nome do cliente</label>
                  <input type="text" name="clienteNome" id="clientes"  class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do cliente">

            </div>
          </div>
                  <input type="hidden" name="clienteId" id="clienteId" >      
      </form>
```

> jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Captura o retorno do retornaCliente.php
    $.getJSON('php/retornar_cliente.php', function(data){
    var dados = [];
    // Armazena na array capturando somente o nome do EC
    $(data).each(function(key, value) {
        dados.push(value.clienteNome);
    });
    // Chamo o Auto complete do JQuery ui setando o id do input, array com os dados e o mínimo de caracteres para disparar o AutoComplete
    $('#clientes').autocomplete({ source: dados, minLength: 3});
    });
});// JavaScript Document
```

> retornar_cliente.php

```
<?php
$hostname = "";
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$basedados = "";
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=adv; charset=utf8;",'root','');
$dados = $pdo->prepare("SELECT clienteNome, clienteId FROM cliente ORDER BY clienteNome");
$dados->execute();
echo json_encode($dados->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a função [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select), ela é chamada toda vez que um item do menu é selecionado.

```
$('#clientes').autocomplete({
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#clienteId').val(ui.item.id);
    console.log('Objeto selecionado: ' + ui.item);
  }
  source: dados,
  minLength: 3
});
```

Comment: desta forma ele envia o nome para o input.. mas eu preciso do ID daquele nome

Comment: Coloquei errado, basta trocar pela propriedade que desejar. O item é o seu elemento. Veja a resposta editada.

Comment: troquei mas nao aconteceu nada :|

Comment: ta certo a minha função .each?

Comment: no  console só aparece "undefined"

Comment: Tente ver o que tem no `ui` apenas. E navegue entre as propriedades. Por padrão o `item` irá trazer o `objeto` selecionado da lista que você adicionou no `source`.